# XML parsing with PHP: how to use foreach

Tags: php, xml, parsing, simplexml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<response docVer="1.0">
    <result code="0">OK</result>
    <engineVer value="2.0.8"/>
    <repInfo>
        <version value="2.0.6.25180"/>
        <expansion value="HotS"/>
        <gameLength gameTimeValue="840" unit="sec" value="606"/>
        <gameLength unit="frame" value="53760"/>
        <gameType value="AutoMM"/>
        <isCompetitive value="true"/>
        <gameSpeed value="Faster"/>
        <format value="2v2"/>
        <gateway value="Europe"/>
        <mapFile value="40/63/4063ce2135431de8ebea926f4263876e8e554d893262bf50718edd0556cf0920.s2ma"/>
        <clients count="2">
            <client index="0" value="[Angels]KoT"/>
            <client index="1" value="SCIIGears"/>
        </clients>
```

I am using `$parsed = new SimpleXMLElement($result);`.

How can I loop through all clients and extract their values for `echo`?

Player 1: nick-name

Player 2: nick-name

and so on. I am stuck with that `foreach`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simplest way to do it is with an XPath, like this (for example):

```
foreach ($parsed->xpath("//client") as $client) {
    echo $client->value;  // ... for example
}
```

The string `"//client"` picks any `<client>` element anywhere in the document.

Comment: And that worked fine too! Like that: `foreach ($parsed->xpath("//client") as $client) {
    echo $client['value'];  // ... for example
}`

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you are looking for?

```
foreach($parsed->repInfo->clients->client as $client)
{
     // do what you want, $client->attribute;
}
```

Comment: Thx, that worked fine: `foreach($parsed->repInfo->clients->client as $client)
{
 echo "<br>" . $client['value'];`
}